# Undefined name "imageList" when i used PageView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, undefined

I tried to fix it by anyway by import,... but it still running error!

[Error]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Jhv.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqhLT.png

Comment: Try `LeadingImages.imageList` ??

Comment: Yes, but it is still error

Comment: Don't put images of code. just post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LeadingImages().imageList` instead of imageList

Comment: making `imageList` static and using `LeadingImages.imageList` is probably better, but your solution should also work